# GoogleMaps on Monodroid, Error Compilation on Mac

Tags: c#, android, google-maps, xamarin.android

How can i make it work the Maps Demo of xamarin on Google's API 10 (2.3.3)?, im trying to run the maps demo app with the google maps api that Monodroid provides and it doesnt work, it always appear Java.IO.Exception: 27, Java.IO.Exception: 28, and so on. Im trying to work with that since December and i dont see any solution of that. Im working on Mac with Monodevelop IDE. Does anyone have a solution?

Edit:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent">
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="0oqo66omATbRfB2Wpsdf6Kpi9-fm88CsqwHauLg"
    />
```

Here is my permission on the Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="cdcsoftwareerpmobileandroid.cdcsoftwareerpmobileandroid">
<application android:label="CdcSoftware.ErpMobile.AndroidUI" android:debuggable="true">
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION">
</uses-permission>
<uses-sdk /></manifest>
```

And this is the MapActivity Class which i commented a line to test both options:

```
public class MapAddress : MapActivity
{
    const String TAG = "MapViewCompassDemo";

    private SensorManager sensor_manager;
    private RotateView rotate_view;
    private MyLocationOverlay location_overlay;

    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
        //SetContentView (Resource.Layout.mapview);


        // Get a reference to the sensor manager
        sensor_manager = (SensorManager) GetSystemService (Context.SensorService);

        // Create our view
        var map_view = new MapView (this, "0oqo66dsfTbRfB2Wp0Lr6Kpi9-fm88CsqwHauLg");

        rotate_view = new RotateView (this);
        rotate_view.AddView (map_view);

        SetContentView (rotate_view);

        // Create the location overlay
        location_overlay = new MyLocationOverlay (this, map_view);
        location_overlay.RunOnFirstFix (delegate {
            map_view.Controller.AnimateTo (location_overlay.MyLocation);
        });
        map_view.Overlays.Add (location_overlay);

        map_view.Controller.SetZoom(18);
        map_view.Clickable = true;
        map_view.Enabled = true;
    }

    protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
        get { return false; }
    }
}
```

Note: The Api Key there is not the real one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize that my problem was my apiKey, i got my fingerprint from another directory: ~/.android/debug.keystore and i didnt think that was the problem, because i generate with it in order to obtain my apikey and i use it in my Java android app and was working fine, but then i try change it to the debug.store that is located in this directory: $HOME/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore, and throws me another fingerprint, so i use it to generate another apikey, and then magically works my app on Mono. But thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 3):

I'm using monodroid and I've got the map working.. you are running the demo? have you got your debug.kestore registered and get the google map API key for a start? here is some notes I had when I was trying to get it work

[Steps to obtain google map API key](http://docs.xamarin.com/android/advanced_topics/Obtaining_a_Google_Maps_API_Key)

=> (Note: Debug.keystore is stored in your Xamarin folder, unlike those java apps)

1. Install Google Inc. Sdk
2. Obtain signing key fingerprint
3. Obtain Map API key
4. Use Map API key in the app

After that, to display map, use

```
<com.google.android.maps.MapView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:apiKey="[MY API KEY]" />
```

Or programatically:

```
var map_view = new MapView (this, "[MY API KEY]");
```

This means you need to substitute some codes in the Demo

if you are using the MapDemo from Mono, somehow only the one with compass works for me. but just make a simple map app like theirs and both methods (putting API key in layout file or in the code) will work.

Edit:

For permissions, put these outside the application tag:

```
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <application></application>
```

not sure if this is necessary but in the AssemblyInfo.cs

```
[assembly: UsesPermission(Android.Manifest.Permission.Internet)]
```

for me I simply load a map in the layout like this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/Logout"
      android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
      android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:text="@string/Logout"
    />
  <com.google.android.maps.MapView
      android:id="@+id/mapview"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:layout_below ="@+id/Logout"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:enabled="true"
      android:clickable="true"
      android:apiKey="API KEY"
        />
  <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/zoom"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
  />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and load it like this:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle); ;
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.mapview);
...
}
```

EDIT:

Just commented some parts to get your code working:

Note:

1. I'm supposing there is something wrong with the sensor and the RotateView because I cannot get it working that way. If you get ride of the RotateView and just add the mapview to a linearLayout dynamically, it will work. For now, if you haven't get the map shown in your app, this is how to show it
2. I changed SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main) to where I put my MapView layout.. just change it back to yours.

   ```
   public class MapAddress : MapActivity
   {
       const String TAG = "MapViewCompassDemo";
       //private SensorManager sensor_manager;
       //private RotateView rotate_view;
       //private MyLocationOverlay location_overlay;   
       protected override void OnCreate (Bundle savedInstanceState)
       {
           base.OnCreate (savedInstanceState);
           SetContentView (Resource.Layout.Main);


           // Get a reference to the sensor manager
       //    sensor_manager = (SensorManager) GetSystemService (Context.SensorService);

           // Create our view
     /*      var map_view = new MapView (this, "0oeB7V1XvegNHY25V5kJq0dsGz_HPbzZa-0WCkg");

           rotate_view = new RotateView (this);
           rotate_view.AddView (map_view);

           SetContentView (rotate_view);

           // Create the location overlay
           location_overlay = new MyLocationOverlay (this, map_view);
           location_overlay.RunOnFirstFix (delegate {
               map_view.Controller.AnimateTo (location_overlay.MyLocation);
           });
           map_view.Overlays.Add (location_overlay);

           map_view.Controller.SetZoom(18);
           map_view.Clickable = true;
           map_view.Enabled = true;
           */
       }

       protected override bool IsRouteDisplayed {
           get { return false; }
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: i use it in Eclipse IDE, and works fine. And i replace my Api key as you said before like the example, and it always returns me these exception: Couldn't get connection factory client, IOException processing: 26, java.io.IOException: Server returned 3 and so on, because i know that the code is ok, i think it could be somthing else, and as i mentioned before, im developing on Googles API 10(2.3.3). And i need a solution for that, not using another API version.

Comment: Okay bud I see what you mean. If you are using the MapsDemo, there are 2 options in the start up activity right? The MapView is giving you the errors and the MapView and Compass is working fine, shows the map and all but also shows some different error in the output? Thats the case for me anyway and that was what happened when I started to develop my app.. As long as you can see the map from the 'MapView and Compass', you are ready to develop your app..

Comment: I'm not really sure what is happening in the demo, but I can use same code for my app and there is no error, as long as you added the right permissions. The kind of error you are saying is like what will happen when you only see the grey grid. Couldn't get connection factory client is sth Mono does a lot so it don't matter. If it is the case you can run the app but only see grey grid then check the permission above, I editted the answer

Comment: Okay. I copied your codes, made a solution from them, and yes, it is giving the error you said. I made 2 changes to get the map shown: 1. Change the API key to my valid debug.keystore API key  2. Change the code in activity to above, as I editted in my answer.

Comment: i realise that my problem was my apiKey, i got my fingerprint from another directory: ~/.android/debug.keystore and i didnt think that was the problem, because i generate with it in order to obtain my apikey and i use it in my Java android app and was working fine, but then i try change it to the debug.store that is located in this directory: $HOME/.local/share/Xamarin/Mono for Android/debug.keystore, and throws me another fingerprint, so i use it to generate another apikey, and then magically works my app on Mono. But thank you very much for your help.

Comment: haha right, I should have thought about that, they are under different directory. Glad it worked for you :)